# How are Inertial Confinement Fusion reactors and Hypersonic Projectile fusion reactors going to generate continuous energy?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, fusion

Perhaps I have not investigated enough, but all the recent (and older) news articles about the Ignition Facility in northern California and the First Light reactor in the UK fail to state how they are going to produce a continuous amount of heat, presumably to either boil water or warm up a thermocouple, and thereby give us some electricity.....

Comment: Well, NIF was never intended to produce energy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in all known fusion devices, magnetic, inertial or by projectile, it will be necessary to recover the thermal energy on the walls of the containment enclosure.
But we have not reached this industrial stage.
Note that ITER will have an enclosure cooling system, and the JET is already water-cooled.